# Not able to get two behaviour to work together on mega menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi So I'm kind of stuck at a problem here,

I have a mega menu with two behaviours that can't seem to get it to work at the same time.

**Behaviour one:**

- When .mega-menu-link is clicked, it's child .megamenu-item will have a class .show added
  and the .megamenu-item child .sgds-icon will rotate 180deg.
- if the active .mega-menu-link's sibling is clicked, the current active mega-menu-link child .megamenu-item will have .show removed and the .megamenu-item child .sgds-icon will rotate back to 0deg

**Behaviour two:**

- When .mega-menu-link is clicked, it's child .megamenu-item will have a class .show added
  and the .megamenu-item child .sgds-icon will rotate 180deg.
- When the same active .mega-menu-link is clicked again, it's child .megamenu-item will have the class .show removed and the .megamenu-item child .sgds-icon will rotate 0deg.

I could get both of to work on it's own but when I try to combine it, the second behaviour won't work properly. The .megamenu-item .show class is removed but the .sgds-icon refused to rotate back to 0deg

here is the jQuery I have so far
`

```
JQUERY 


window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    $('li.mega-menu-link').on('click', function (e) {
        var menuItem = $(e.currentTarget);
        
        menuItem.parent().children('li.mega-menu-link').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
        menuItem.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
        menuItem.parent().children().children('.megamenu-item').removeClass('show');

        if ($('.megamenu-item').hasClass('show')){

            menuItem.parent().children().children().children('.sgds-icon').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
            menuItem.children().children('.sgds-icon').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
        } {
            menuItem.parent().children().children().children('.sgds-icon').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
            menuItem.children().children('.sgds-icon').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
        }
    });
});
```

`
here's a js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6gdvjkq0/2/

Comment: The problem is quite simple: if you click on a child, you automatically also click on it's parent.

Also, why are you checking for `$('.megamenu-item').hasClass('show')`? Don't you wanna check it on the current clicked item (`menuItem.hasClass('show')`)?

Comment: @Kathara hi! I dont quite understand what you mean by if you click on a child , you automatically also click on a parent, is there an example you can show me please?

Comment: I've created a pen to show it: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/KKeVPOe
If you click on the parent, only the parent receives a background-color. If you click on the child, both of them receive a background color. So the click on the child automatically triggers the click of the parent as the child is part of the parent.